# TFS get latest version does not restore references

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a project that i have been developing on my machine that is checked into source control (tfs).

I would now like another developer to work on the project with me. They have connected to the tfs server and configured the local workspace. However when they say "get latest version", it downloads the project as expected, NUGET restores the packages as expected. But pretty much all of the references to the packages show up as missing and thus the project will not compile.

Here is a screenshot of the issue.

[image]

Here is my NuGet.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
</configuration>
```

and here is my .tfignore file

```
\packages
!\packages\repositories.config
```

I'm not quite sure what the issue could be. We are both using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 2 with TFS Express 2015 Update 2.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to check what those references look like in the .csproj file, open it up in notepad or similar and look at the references.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen what in particular would i be looking for? Here is an example of a reference

`<Reference Include="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\log4net.1.2.10\lib\2.0\log4net.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>`

This matches the machine where the packages are working. Thanks

Comment: And is that folder correct on the machine where they don't?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The folder structure is the same on both machines.

I've just tried removing the local copy of the project and getting the latest version of the project. I can see the packages restoring to the packages folder, but they are still showing as missing in the actual project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the end was that although i had created the .tfignore file, i had already checked in the packages folder into source control so this was having no effect.

Deleting the packages folder from the code section in the tfs webpage resolved this issue and packages now restore as expected on new target machines.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

1. Check whether the Nuget Package Manager has updated to the latest version
2. Check the Nuget Package Manager setting in VS, make sure the items below are selected:

**Allow NuGet to download missing packages**

**Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio**

[image]

Comment: this is already set in Visual Studio. The packages do restore to /packages, but the project shows them as missing references.

Comment: Try deleting the packages folder and building again.